# Parameter values in request

Tags: jsp, request

I want to know whether the parameter values in request change after submission of values updated by the user in the form fields.

For example

A form has following text field name

```
     Name
     Organisation
     Mobile number
```

When user requests the page the values of the corresponding parameters get stored in the request. Now if the Organisation and Mobile Number values are changed, are the values in the request corresponding to Organisation and Mobile Number get changed?

Comment: Why would the request still exist once you've already sent the response for this request?

Comment: How do you change the values once the form has been submitted . Are you using ajax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand the life cycle of jsp ,

[image]

For every request submitted from browser , the container will generate the response to the it. so the request in no longer available in the client side to access once you submit your for successfully (*differs clicking the submit button*)

> Now if the Organisation and Mobile Number values are changed, are the
>   values in the request corresponding to Organisation and Mobile Number
>   get changed?

So once the `HttpRequest` is sent to the server the values in the request cant be changed until you initiate the next request